# Backward compatibility of WPF application created using dot net frame work 4.5

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, backwards-compatibility

Am creating a `WPF application` using `Microsoft Dot net Frame Work 4.5` version targeting Windows 8. I wanted to make my application to be run on previous Windows OS versions like Windows xp ,Vista & Windows 7. 
 
 I think For Windows 7 it is ok . But What about Windows xp / Vista compatibility ? Will my application work with those OS? 
If any idea please share.

Comment: You'll have to drop XP support because .Net 4.5 won't run on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to downgrade to .net 4.0 to support windows xp (service pack 2 and above only).

Be prepared to refactor any `async` or `await` methods.

Comment: .NET Framework Versions and Dependencies:-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you are using `async` or `await`, Microsoft does have the [ASync Targeting Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).  If not using these keywords, it's worth a shot making a separate build targeting the 4.0 framework, but as mentioned you won't be able to have a single build targeting 4.5 that works on all systems.